# presentRenderbuffer EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-motion

I use `CoreMotion` to get the shake acceleration value like this:

```
-(void)startAccelerometer {
    [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init]
                                             withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                                 [self outputAccelertionData:accelerometerData.acceleration];
                                                 if (error) {
                                                     NSLog(@"motion error:%@",error);
                                                 }
                                             }];
}

-(void)outputAccelertionData:(CMAcceleration)acceleration {
    double accelerameter =sqrt( pow( acceleration.x , 2 ) + pow( acceleration.y , 2 )
                               + pow( acceleration.z , 2) );
    if (accelerameter>2.3f) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"shaked" object:[NSValue value:&acceleration withObjCType:@encode(CMAcceleration)]];
        });
    }
}
```

And in my another glView controller, observing the `shaked` notification and do `render` stuff, but It often crashed in `[self.glContext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];` line, see stack trace:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but did you ever find the answer to this?